# TemplateSyntaxError in Django

Tags: python, django

I am following the django app tutorial and I get this error...

```
Invalid block tag on line 5: 'endfor', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
Django Version: 1.10.1
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:
Invalid block tag on line 5: 'endfor', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Exception Location: C:\Python34\Orange\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in invalid_block_tag, line 568
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\Orange\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.4
Python Path:
['C:\xampp\htdocs\django\mysite',
 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\python34.zip',
 'C:\Python34\Orange\DLLs',
 'C:\Python34\Orange\lib',
 'C:\Python34\Orange',
 'C:\Python34\Orange\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 29 Oct 2016 21:30:59 +0300

My index.html looks like this...

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
<ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list % }
    <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{question.question_text}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No polls available</p>{% endif %}
```

What am I doing wrong? Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a space between the `%` and the closing `}` on the `for` tag, so Django doesn't recognise it. Remove that.